# How do you append to a Hive array?

Tags: hive

I have a Hive table where for a user ID I have a ts column, which is a timeseries, stored as array.  I want to maintain the timeseries as a recentmost window.

(a) how do I append a new number to the end of each column from another table joined by ID?
(b) how do I drop the leading number?

Answer (score 0):

Data in Hive is typically stored in HDFS. HDFS has limited append capabilities. If the constant modification of data is at the core of your analytics systems, then perhaps you should consider using alternatives like HBase or Cassandra.

However, if the data updates are a small part of your workflow, I would encourage you to continue using Hive (in order to make use of it's SQL like functionality) but reconsider your design for storing these updates.

A quick solution to your above problem would be to have more than one record per user ID in your table. Each record would have a timeseries corresponding to the User ID. When you want to do your last N analysis on the timeseries, you should do a select from the table by using by [Distribute By](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-transform.html) on User ID column. Your custom reducer will simply pick out the last N (or less, if the size of the timeseries is less than N) timestamps and return them.

Harish Butani also did some work on Windowing functions in Hive. You can also take a look at [his work](https://github.com/hbutani/SQLWindowing) and [associated documentation](https://github.com/hbutani/SQLWindowing/blob/master/docs/Windowing.pdf) to gain some more insight. Good luck, Alexy!